# ionic 3 different side menu per tab selected

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to have a different side menu when selecting tabs from below. I mean I want my side menus to change when I select a tab.

Can I do this?

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0):

One way is to apply (on each item in your menu) a conditional class:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

as an example `app.html`:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <!-- The side menu title -->
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>{{loc.translate.MENU}}</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <!-- Show  toggle only when first tab -->
            <ion-item [class.hidden]="currentTab == firstTab" >
                <ion-toggle (ionChange)="toggled()" ></ion-toggle>
                <ion-label>Switch Wifi</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <!-- Show only when first tab -->
            <button [class.hidden]="currentTab == firstTab"  ion-item menuToggle>
                <ion-icon item-start name="close"></ion-icon>tab 1 says hello
            </button>
            <!-- Show only when second tab -->
            <button [class.hidden]="currentTab == secondTab" ion-item menuToggle>
                <ion-icon item-start name="close"></ion-icon>tab 2 says hello
            </button>
            <!-- Show only when third tab -->
            <button [class.hidden]="currentTab == thirdTab" ion-item menuToggle>
                <ion-icon item-start name="close"></ion-icon>tab 3 item here
            </button>
            <!-- Show always -->
            <button ion-item menuToggle>
                <ion-icon item-start name="close"></ion-icon>CLose Menu
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

and on your `app.component.ts` youll make your way to getting the current Page (or tab) and have your properties `firstTab`, `secondTab` and such be defined as the pages so that you can have it compared with the current page.